# PCB power supply

Tags: pcb

Hi I'm an absolute beginner,
I ordered a sony clock radio from the states figuring I could swap the plug in power supply to a 240v. When I received it I was surprised to find the plug in 120v power supply was hard wired in.As there were no markings on the outside or the inside for that matter of the supplied plug pack I had a peak at the PCB of the device and saw a 10v capacitor so I took a punt and hooked it up to a 12VDC power supply.....heard a little pop and then the dreaded smell.
My question(s)is could this have been because I had the polarity wrong? Or more likely the supply voltage? 
And is there any chance it is recoverable?

Comment: It's all about researching your purchase and delving into the detail. Seasoned EE guys do this and don't usually get caught out.

Comment: Why would you connect a 12V supply to a 10V capacitor?

Comment: Chances are almost 100% it's not economically repairable, but it probably wouldn't have worked properly on 50Hz anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With a 10V capacitor the expected supply is going to be <= 8VDC.

Not to mention that there might be more than one voltage used, for example 5V and 3.3V, both made by the supply unit, or 9V and 5V, for different parts of the device. It's also possible the PCB makes the lower voltage itself, if it needs it.

Put simply: You definately put 12VDC somewhere where it did not belong something rated at 10V *never* takes any more than that, capacitors usually take a measurable bit less in fact. You might also have put it the wrong way around. From the way you ask your question you did not look to find out which belonged where, so it'll be a 50/50 shot. 50/50 shots in Electronics are pretty much a don't try to begin with, unless otherwise it's throw-away anyway.